# Move MS Access tables to be used in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, migrate

I'm using MS Access 2013.  I have a some tables which I would like to migrate to SQL Server 2012 (Management Studio).  I want these tables to be used in SQL Server for addition etc., but I also want these tables to show as 'linked' in MS Access.

How do I make it so the tables look populated in MS Access, but are manipulated from SQL Server?

The Migration tool in SQL Server did not give me my desired results.

Comment: Well, "not desired results" is un-clear. Did the tables move to SQL server and did you check/view SQL server with the SQL management studio? After you transfer tables to SQL server, then you can and should be able to simply link to those tables using the external data tab of the ribbon and choose ODBC.

Comment: The tables were located there, but there was no indication of there being a link in Access.  Having observed another person's project, I noticed the indicator over the tables showing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to move it to SQL server from Access.  If you say it is just for addition purposes, that is a really bad idea to move from Access.

You will need to create a shell database in SQL Server.
From Access select > External Data > More > ODBC Database and follow the prompts to export the data into SQL Server.

After that select > External Data under Import and Link > ODBC Database
This will link the local Access table to the SQL Server table and you will be able to run queries you require.

Comment: I'm doing this on behalf of someone else.  They say that Access has "too many restrictions".

I received an error during the move - it looked as if it would be successful for a bit.

ODBC--call failed.

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded. (#7609)

Comment: Try SQL Server Configuration Manger-> SQL Server(./SQL Express) (properties)

 Set the "Enable file Stream for Transact-SQL Access"

Answer (score 0):

1. **Create Database in SQL Server** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312.aspx#SSMSProcedure
2. **Migrate Data from Access to SQL Server**. For Access 2013 you will need to use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. Search the start menu for "Import and Export Wizard". It comes installed with SQL Server. For the data source choose Microsoft Access and follow the steps.
3. **How do I make it so the tables look populated in MS Access, but are manipulated from SQL Server?** Create a linked table via ODBC connection. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e